# Декодировать и закодировать uint16 значение в три блока

Tags: golang, битовые-операции

Посмотрел несколько видео про побитовые операции, и понял что вроде бы все так легко, а на практике ничего не понятно

Задача: Из uint16 значения извлечь 3 первых бита - это приоритетность модуля, 4 бит это инкапсулируется ли модуль, оставшиеся 12 бит это идентификатор модуля. И также закодировать три входящих uint16 значения в один выходной uint16

Я вообще не понимаю как это сделать

```go
valPrior := uint16(6) // from 0-7
valEncap := uint16(1) // yes encaplulating 
valId := uint16(1873) // from 0-4095
```

Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Предположим в encoded хранится число 
// 0101 0101 0101 1101

// побитовое "И" с числом 
// 0000 0000 0000 0111
// дает
// 0000 0000 0000 0101
var valPrior uint16 = encoded & 7
// побитовое смешение на 3 бита вправо дает
// 0000 1010 1010 1011
// далее с побитовым "И" с числом 1 образует 1
var valEncap uint16 = ( encoded >> 3 ) & 1
// здесь такое же смещение на 4 бита вправо
var valId uint16 = encoded >> 4

// обратное преобразование
var encoded uint16 = (valId << 4) | (valEncap << 3) | valPrior
```

Дополню ответ небольшой теоретической выкладкой.

Принцип объединения маленьких чисел в одно большое очень прост:

1. Сначала в переменную объединённого числа помещается значение первого малого числа.
2. Затем сдвигаем значение объединённого числа влево (`<<`) на количество значимых бит следующего числа, сохраняя получившееся значение в переменную объединённого числа.
3. Объединяем значение следующего числа с значением переменной объединённого числа, используя логическое ИЛИ (`|`) и сохраняем получившееся значение в переменную объединённого числа.
4. Есть ли другие малые числа? Если такие числа ещё не кончились, возвращаемся к шагу 2. Если других чисел больше нет, то работа завершена, переменная объединённого числа содержит целевое значение.

По сравнению с аналогами этот алгоритм наиболее прост в реализации и самый быстрый. Позволяет собирать неограниченное количество чисел в много-гигабайтовые буферы со скоростью близкой к максимальной пропускной способности RAM.

Есть пара очевидных тонкостей. Во-первых, изначально необходимо рассчитывать суммарное количество значимых бит, и оно не должно превышать количество бит в общем буфере.

Во-вторых. Если есть вероятность, что значение одного или нескольких малых чисел превысит диапазон допустимых своим количеством значимых бит значений, то можно перестраховаться, пропустив значение каждого числа через маску логического И (`&`).

Чаще всего маска представляет из себя значение с забитым количеством единиц в младших разрядах. Количество единиц равно количеству значимых бит. Само значение маски рассчитывается по формуле 2<sup>n</sup>-1, где `n = 1 + количество_значимых_бит`. Вот отсюда и берутся эти числа: `1` (1 значимый бит), `3` (2 бита), `7` (3 бита), `15` (4 бита), `31` (5 бит), `63` (6), `127` (7), `255` (8), `511` (9), `1023` (10), `2047` (11), `4095` (12), `8191` (13), `16383` (14), `32767` (15), `65535` (16 бит) и так далее.

Стоит также иметь в виду, что операции побитового сдвига (`<<` и `>>`) имеют больший приоритет, чем операции побитовых И (`&`) ИЛИ (`|`) и XOR (`^`), но меньший приоритет перед базовыми математическими операциями (`+` и `-`). Это сложно сразу запомнить, но в любом случае желательно не скупиться на скобочки, принудительно расставляя приоритеты операций - это поможет избежать возникновения неявных ошибок.

Чтобы узнать сколько бит необходимо для кодирования числа `n`, можно извлечь из логарифм по основанию 2 из `n+1` и получившийся результат округлить до единиц в большую сторону. Если на калькуляторе, что под рукой, нет возможности задать основание логарифма, то же значение можно найти используя натуральный или десятичный логарифм по формуле: `log(n+1) / log(2)` опять же, округляя результат до единиц в большую сторону.

Обратное преобразование большого числа в малые производится в зеркально обратном порядке.

1. Начиная от последней переменной (в обратном порядке), получаем значение малой переменной из общего значения пропуская его через маску (с необходимым количеством значимых бит для текущего малого числа) через логическое И (`&`).
2. Далее сдвигаем общее значение вправо на количество значимых бит прошлой переменной из шага `1` и сохраняем значение в переменной общего значения.
3. Повторяем шаги `1` и `2` заполняя значениями все переменные с малыми числами кроме одной. При кодировании та переменная была самой первой. Переменная с общим большим числом должна уже иметь значение той самой первой переменной с малым числом, которая вносилась в общее значение без предварительного сдвига. И, получается, её значение можно уже не пропускать через маску со значимым количеством бит. Работа завершена.

Как я упоминал выше, это не единственный способ кодирования нескольких чисел в одном числе. Существуют разные алгоритмы сжатия значений, в том числе и с контролем выявления ошибок чтения, и даже с возможностью устранения этих ошибок по избыточным данным. Например, [Код Левенштейна](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0), [Код Хэмминга](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%A5%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0) и др.

Comment: хороший ответ. продолжайте также

Comment: Честно говоря, я вообще не понял зачем первым действие у нас побитовое И на 7 (это суммарно 3 + 4 дает семерку?) Затем мы смещаем на 3 бита вправо и сверяем является ли бит положительным, а затем еще на 4 бита в право и оставшуюся часть получаем valId. Но код вообще мне дает другое представление. 

https://go.dev/play/p/OXNe7EQdN28
Вот пример кода который пытаюсь запустить

Comment: @Mothership 3 + 4 не причем. Смотрите `3 = 0b0011` `5 = 0b0101` вместе они ("или") `3 | 5 = 7 0b0111`, совпадают ("и") `3 & 5 = 1 0b0001` разнятся ("xor") `3^5 = 6 0b0110` сдвиг вправо `6 >> 1 = 3 0b0011` сдвиг влево `6 << 1 = 12 0b1100`. где `0b` - бинарное представление числа. Попробуйте записать их в один столбик и увидеть биты.

Comment: @Mothership Дополнил ответ теорией. Также для вас смастерил [демку](https://codepen.io/zazaulola/full/VwMNwpz) с иллюстраций битовых операций. Также настоятельно рекомендую ознакомиться с статьями Википедии, на которые я оставил ссылки в конце ответа. Код Левенштейна позволяет кодировать числа в битовый поток, который восстанавливается в исходные числа не имея структуры данных. То есть размеры чисел выясняются из самого битового потока. Код Хэмминга еще более интересный. Имея 5%ную избыточность данных появляется возможность восстановить повреждения любых байтов массива до порогового количества

Comment: @DiD спасибо Вам большое добрый человек что дали настолько развернутый ответ!) Перечитал несколько раз, чтобы понять, и о чудо до меня дошло как это работает)) Теперь осталось попрактиковаться чтобы точно закрепить теорию практикой